# Differences between DDD & MDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I would like to know if there is any difference between:

Domain Driven Design (DDD)
Model Driven Design (MDD)
I always find these two terms in many articles and public literature, but no one highlights the differences.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Domain Driven Design vs Model Driven Architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166816/domain-driven-design-vs-model-driven-architecture)

Comment: At the same time there are no really good answers there...

Comment: I'm reading the book "Domain Driven Design". In the book, the author uses DDD and MDD interchangeably, so I guess they are just the same thing?

Comment: Here's the answer by Evans himself: https://www.dddcommunity.org/uncategorized/evans_2004/

Answer (score 6):

I personally find MDA and DDD quite far away from each other.

MDA focuses on creating different kind of models that describe software systems on different levels. It encourages using UML for these models and there could be a lot of those models produced to describe quite complex systems from different perspectives. There were some solutions created, like Rational Rose, to generate software from models and keep them in sync with the code.

At the same time MDA says nothing about how you communicate to the business to understand their problem domain. All MDA focuses on is the solution domain.

DDD, at the other hand, is much more about the knowledge about the domain and about the language. In short, many describe DDD as "developing Ubiquitous Language inside Bounded Contexts". You are encouraged to talk to domain experts and understand what are they saying. You need to define contexts where these terms make sense, since the difference in terminology in different contexts can be tremendously different. Each context is then isolated into a highly cohesive component, and a composition of those components form a complete system.

There are many tactical patterns in DDD like aggregate root, entity, value object, repository and factory. But their main goal is to give developers some tools to create proper abstractions, which can encapsulate the domain knowledge without compromising the code readability.

The most important part of DDD is in strategic patterns like bounded contexts, context map and ubiquitous language. If you are not using this - you have no DDD. And it does not matter, which notation you use to draw diagrams (some just use sticky notes), this is completely secondary.

Answer (score 0):

The two design approaches are very similar. Check out this StackOverflow link for some great, detailed answers on this topic:

[Domain Driven Design vs Model Driven Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166816/domain-driven-design-vs-model-driven-architecture)

To summarize the answers in the link, both approaches focus on accurately modeling a problem before designing a solution. In general, DDD is considered more abstract, with no specifically suggested technologies or design tools. MDD/MDA is considered more specific, with suggestions to use UML for design work.

Comment: Downvoter, could you please explain what you disliked, so answers to the question can be improved?

Comment: I did not downvote, but the common practice is to mark the question as duplicate rather than answering and referencing the other question.

Comment: Thanks, plalx!  It definitely seems like a duplicate, but I don't have the rep to comment or mark questions yet :)

Comment: *"The two design approaches are very similar"* - you're gonna upset some people here :)

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right about that :) Would love to get some feedback from people with more practical experience using these approaches though.